# Copy to clipboard from command line

Tags: command-line, clipboard, xclip

Trying to copy to clipboard from command line by using command:

```
xclip /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Trying to get out from clipboard:

```
xclip -o
```

This prints the content of `sources.list` and it is fine.

But now I try to paste into `eclipse` project and got some old clipboard content. Looks like `xclip` uses its internal clipboard.

How to copy into system clipboard from command line?

Comment: Try pasting using your middle mouse button into eclipse, after using the `xclip /etc/apt/sources.list` command

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the `clipboard`, instead of the default `primary` X selection:

```
xclip -o -selection clipboard
```

Or, if you use `xsel` instead, another tool with the same functionality, you just need the short option `-b`:

```
xsel -ob
```